# basic question: creating a button (or anything)

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new to Android development and Java (learning both simultaneously sort of...).

My question is: if I set up a button in main.xml, I still need to actually create the button in my Activity, right? Like the XML just controls the look of the button, but you need to actually create a button by doing something like

```
private Button myButton;
```

Just wanted to make sure I had this clear conceptually. You create an object in your class and then just tell Android to do something like

```
myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Just wanted to make sure I'm clear on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you would need to do.

#### Update:

Just to help you further conceptualize the process, Android uses the `main.xml` for your widgets (such as your `Button`) and different layouts. This is where you would need to *define* your widget.

Now inside of your project, you would need to *create* your widget variable,

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Once your `myButton` object is created, you can then start adding functionality to the button, such as what it should do when clicked, (*although that can be defined in your `main.xml` file with `android:onClick` attribute*)

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
  // code to process Button click
}
```

I hope this clarifies things a bit, if you need me to elaborate at any points please let me know.

Comment: Could I just use View myButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);

?

And skip the need to use private Button myButton; at the beginning of my class?

Comment: Not exactly. You are returning a `View` object from `findViewById` but you need to cast (which is the `(Button`) notation) to a `Button` object.

Comment: @LuxuryMode, I removed my code reference just to avoid any confusion. You are on the correct track when setting up the `Button`. Let me know if you have any other further questions.

Comment: @LuxuryMode, I had edited my answer to help you conceptualize the purpose of the `main.xml` file and your class. If this was too much, please let me know.

Comment: Anthony, perfect! Really appreciate your help. I've got a lot of work. I'm reading a book on Java and trying to learn Android dev at the same time. I'm beginning to find that the only way to really do this is to try to just jump in head first and create an app and just work through the different issues as they arise.

Comment: @LuxuryMode, Keep on trucking! If you have any questions, it is good to note that the author of many Android related books is an active member in this community. If you have any troubles, SO is a good place to turn.

Comment: "Now inside of your project, you would need to create the widget"
The widget is already created from the xml definition, you're just referencing it inside the java code.

Comment: I agree with you, but before referencing it you must *create* your `Button` object. I tried to differentiate the purpose and process of the `main.xml` file and the project file.

Comment: Weeeeeell, you're not creating a button object but declaring a variable to which you assign a reference of an existing button object...but your explanation is definitely easier for beginners to understand (even if technically not quite right)

Comment: @Alex, I had edited the answer to reference that you are creating a widget variable opposed to an object. If you feel the need that I would need to expand upon anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Yea, the thing I'm a bit confused about is that when I run my program it displayed both buttons that I defined in my XML, even though I only actually "created" one button object in my class. It seems like "setContentView(R.layout.main); makes the Activity display all of the buttons defined in main, no?

Comment: @LuxuryMode, Yeah it will display the widget objects you defined in your `main.xml` file.

Comment: I guess this is fine, not that it was bad before.  However, I don't think that your answer is correct given LuxuryMode's question on whether the Button variable NEEDED to be declared to use the button, and the answer should be NO.  I provided a separate answer below which demonstrates how to reference the Button object without declaring a Button variable, but your answer demonstrates good coding practice, which is also good and better for beginners like LxuryMode.

Comment: @LuxuryMode.  Yes, you're right.  setContentView() will instantiate all of the objects that you have defined in your xml file.  You can read a little about object instantiation here: http://www.javaying.com/2006/10/class-instantiation.html

Comment: Trying to follow the convo here. The button objects exist even if you don't do Button mybutton, etc? Button mybutton is just setting up a reference variable so you can control that button?

Comment: Would love to chat with either/both of you guys about Android dev. Interested to hear about your background and how you got into Android dev.

Comment: @LuxuryMode, Have you visited the chat section of the site? More specifically, the Android chat room?

Comment: I haven't to the chat room.  Now might not be a good time...I gotta go to bed, but I'm glad that you figured out your problem, LuxuryMode.

Comment: @LuxuryMode Try it out, there are two Android rooms available to chat in. One you must request permission to speak by the owner of the chat room and the other one is open. Android development is not a big hit on this website, so there may not be a lot of people in the room.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting this notification (it's not an error; its one of those yellow things...i'm new to eclipse.) 

On my code that says "private Button myButton;" I am getting a notification that "test.myButton is never read locally." 

Later on in my onCreate method I DO refer to it: Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);

Comment: @LuxuryMode, Its an Eclipse notification telling you that your variable is declared by never used in the local scope, it's not too big of a deal.

Comment: Isn't it in the scope if it's used in my onCreate method?

Comment: @LuxuryMode, Its tough to say without seeing your actual code. Rather than talking within the comments, feel free to talk in the chat room.

Comment: You're not using it, you're just declaring/defining it. The warning is quite clear, your variable is SET, but it's never READ hence it presumably does nothing.

Comment: @Luxury Mode.  What you're doing is declaring two different variables with the name myButton.  One is class level and the other is within the scope of the method.  You ended up using the method level one, hence you got a warning on the class level button declaration. You can either remove the class level declaration, or, the better option, remove the first Button word from the method level line to get this: "myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);" and your class level variable will be used.

Comment: @Alex Thank you. I think that clarifies. You're saying that there are two declarations and that the code ends up using the method one, rending the declaration in the beginning of the class useless. You seem to be saying I should opt for the myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button); approach. What did you mean that I should "remove the first Button word" from the method? My code in original question matches your suggestion, no? Can you clarify what you meant about making it use the class level variable. I'm surprised simply object creation is so confusing. Consensus on best practice?

Comment: In your original question you're doing it right.  However, 6 comments above you added the "Button" word to the beginning of the line, which means that you're declaring the variable of type button with a variable name that follows it.

"Button myButton = bla bla" //declares the variable and assigns to it
"mybutton = bla bla" //assigns to an already declared variable

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't have to declare the button variable.  You can manipulate that button by always calling the findViewById method, like this:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button)).SomeButtonMethod();
```

Personally, I would recommend that you do declare the button variable since you will probably be referencing it more than once and you don't want to waste the cpu on redundant tasks of finding something that has already been found.